# How to select the Visual Studio version to use on the build machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

We have a buildmachine that currently has installed Visual Studio 2010 to compile our application.

Now we have moved to Visual Studio 2015 and developers have installed it on their machines and modified the solution so it works with 2015 but the previous versions will continue to build with 2010.

I was going to install Visual Studio 2015 on the build machine but I don't know how the build machine will know that the previous branches must be built with 2010 and the new ones with 2015. With some Msbuild settings? Just looking at the sln? By other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it does it looking at the ToolsVersion on every .csproj. VisualStudio is not required as MsBuild and the compiler come with the .Net Framework.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. It would be easier if I hadn't to wait 5 minutes between posting and accepting ... :\

Answer (score 1):

> With some Msbuild settings? Just looking at the sln? By other means?

Open your .sln file with Notepad. Look for Format Version on the first line which correlates with a Visual Studio version.

•Format Version 11.00 is Visual Studio 2010

•Format Version 12.00 is Visual Studio 2013 && Visual Studio 2013

For visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2015, we could find the visual studio version on the third line. like this:

visual studio 2013:  VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.30501.0

visual studio 2015:  VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1